# Show animated GIF in Flutter from assets

Tags: flutter, animated-gif

I want to show an animated gif as the background of my home page. Below is my code.

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      new Image(image: new AssetImage('/assets/heaven.gif')),
    ]
  ),
);
```

But it is not showing on the home screen. I'm getting only a white background.

I have added the asset folder in assets in pubspec.yaml. My assets folder path is /lib/assets

```
assets:
- lib/assets/
```

Comment: 1 - remove the leading `/` from the string passed to the constructor. 2 - move the assets folder up one level to `projectFolder/assets`. 3 - edit `pubspec.yaml` to remove the `lib/`.

Comment: Thank you very much @RichardHeap . It worked! Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lib` folder should be used for your source code. Assets should be placed in a different folder at the top of your project - often given the name `assets`.

```
projectFolder -+
               +- pubspec.yaml
               +- /lib
               +- /assets
```

Update the `pubspec.yaml` to reflect the new path `assets/` instead of `assets/lib/`.

Finally change the code to remove the leading `/`. `AssetImage('assets/heaven.gif')` instead of `AssetImage('/assets/heaven.gif')`. (The `new` keyword is optional and can be dropped, too.)